# Javascript regex to parse string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following strings :

```
id,square,vegetable.garden:id<>cell:gardenId
id,square,vegetable.garden:id<>cell:gardenId?id=10
id,square,vegetable.garden:id<>cell:gardenId@toto
id,square,vegetable.garden:id<>cell:gardenId^titi
id,square,vegetable.garden:id<>cell:gardenId?id=10@toto^titi
id,square,vegetable.garden:id<>cell:gardenId@toto^titi
```

With JS I want to match all parameters. I have the regex

```
/(\S*)\.(\S*)([\?@\^])(\S*)([\?@\^])(\S*)([\?@\^])(\S*)/g
```

But this regex matching and catching parameters for the 5th string only. Do you have an solution to match all the strings ?

Thanks for your help.

Sorry if it's not clear.

I have this

```
id,square,vegetable.garden:id<>cell:gardenId?id=10@toto^titi
```

And I want to split parameters to have :

```
group1 = id,square,vegetable
group2 = garden:id<>cell:gardenId
group3 = ?
group4 = id=10
group5 = @
group6 = toto
group7 = ^
group8 = titi
```

The previous regex working. But for other string this regex not working because I can have differents order for @, ^ or ? separator and they can be optionals.

Online RegEx with examples [here](https://regex101.com/r/kagmcQ/1/).

It's more clear ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you only have 3 pieces maximum that it can extend to:
Here's a regex that should work for you: 
`([^\s.]*)\.([^?@^\s]+)(?:([?@^])([^?\s@^]+))?(?:([?@^])([^?\s@^]+))?(?:([?@^])([^?\s@^]+))?`

It matches all the example strings that you gave and seems to match fairly quickly as well.
The repeating bit `(?:([?@^])([^?\s@^]+))?`matches optionally if there is a ?, @, or ^ followed by all the characters that aren't one of them or a whitespace.

https://regex101.com/r/MRzMdK/2

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear what you want to do, but you could try something like this to use a regex to see if a string contains another string:

```js
const str1 = 'id,square,vegetable.garden:id<>cell:gardenId'
const str2 = 'id,square,vegetable.garden:id<>cell:gardenId?id=10'
const str3 = 'id,square,vegetable.garden:id<>cell:gardenId@toto'
const str4 = 'id,square,vegetable.garden:id<>cell:gardenId^titi'
const str5 = 'id,square,vegetable.garden:id<>cell:gardenId?id=10@toto^titi'
const str6 = 'id,square,vegetable.garden:id<>cell:gardenId@toto^titi'

const regex = new RegExp(str1, "ig")
const res = str2.match(regex)
console.log(res)
```